# "System" command from cstdlib does not work in ESXi

Tags: c++, shell, esxi

I am trying to use "system" command from cstdlib library in ESXi OS. It seems that it does not succeed.
Should "system" command from csdtlib work In ESXi system ? Is there any other way to call system command in esxi?

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example formated as a code snipped, so others can reproduce it?

Comment: If there is no shell, you can't call shell commands

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Shell was enabled. It seems that executing that commands was disabled by default in my solution by streams forwarding.